# Low water pressure in shower after turning off main

Tags: water, water-pressure

Had a bad drip in shower. Two handle shower replaced little rubber rings. Turned water back on and the shower barely comes out but all other sinks in the house seem to have plenty of pressure. Is there anything I can check to fix this? Pressure was fine before this.

Thank you

Comment: You should really re word this question , first thought , low water water pressure after turning off the main DUH ,,, ok , I would try to high flow the shower fixture with the cartridge out , probably some "stuff" plugged the line or orifices.

Comment: @EdBeal sounds like an answer...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is some debris have plugged the orifices. I would turn the water off pull the cartridge and try to high flow the lines to clear any debris out. In the past I have found rust & scale plugs blocking valves that worked great after flowing, don't forget to check the shower head itself if it has a screen that could be the location where it is plugged if only a shower head (no tub ).